# Upload multiple files with ngcordova file transfer without $q.all

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

i'm working on a ionic project where you can click on 5(or more) different buttons to select image from library (or camera of course) for each of them.
i want to upload each image immediately after selecting(or capturing) using ngcordova file transfer plugin and show some feedback for the result of each upload after it finished, therefore i need to use success and error callback for each one of my file transfer calls.

the problem is file transfer plugin can only process one upload at a time and if i start to upload a new image before the first upload completes, first upload will get an error and second upload starts. but if i start the second upload after finishing the first upload there will be no problem.

i know i can use $q.all but in that case i will be missing success and error for each promise. how can i solve this problem?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464945/add-queueing-to-angulars-http-service

Comment: @ItaloAyres thanks. this usually must work for processing 1 promise per time. but actually what i found was it will work perfectly when i use just camera to take picture (because android will save each of them with different name). but if use library, because android saves all pictures picked from library with same name, each time i pick a picture previous uploads in queue will break because the file will be changed. can you help with that too?

Comment: Acording [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#upload) you can set the name of the file in the options.  `fileName: The file name to use when saving the file on the server. Defaults to image.jpg.`

Comment: @ItaloAyres . my problem is related to android not the cordova file transfer. when i pick an image from library it gives a path like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.classifiedapp760481/cache/.Pic.jpg when i select another picture it gives me the exact same path for image. so the previous image is not accessible and file transfer plugin can not upload it (even in middle of uploading) and throws error ...

Comment: What image picker are you using?

Comment: the default image picker that comes from cordova camera plugin