# ng-repeat with directive: how to destroy repeated items after array has changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js app, that uses an ng-repeat with a directive like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="n in items">
   <div data-my-directive
        item="n"></div>
</div>
```

where `items` is an array with integers.

Depending on actions of the user, the `items` array can be completely destroyed and made anew with new integers.

First time, it may be [1,2,4,9]
and next it may be [1,3,6,7]
for instance. This is dependent on some user choices.

The directive `my-directive` will perform some business logic server-side, so it will call the server as soon as it gets loaded. And then after a result returns, it shows a nice table to the users.

The problem is that some users don't wait until everything is nice and loaded and switch their view (which means the array changes). In this case, I see that the calls to the server are still being executed and that the result-function is still being called, even though the directive itself has been destroyed because the ngRepeat has rebound and all of the directives are re-made.

For instance:

```
$http.get(service.url + '/filters').success(function(result) {
    alert(result);
 });
```

This will display all of the alerts, even of the directives that are no longer on the page.
This poses a few problems. Can I destroy the directives in the repeat when the array changes or something like that to make sure that no logic is executed in a directive that shouldn't exist anymore (or that isn't displayed on the page anymore) ? 
Or do you have some other ideas on how best to approach this?

Ideally, the directives should just disappear after the ng-repeat has rebound itself, so no logic is executed as soon as data comes back from the server.

Comment: I would lock the screen until the directive has completed its server side job, avoiding that the user changes parameters meanwhile

Comment: I completely agree, but unfortunately the client has deemed that this is not an option. A lot of users accidentally pick the wrong option and then quickly switch to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

When the user changes the parameters you can cancel the running request and start a new one.

[In this Scott Allen's blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx) you can find the detailed explanation of how this work.

You start creating a service or a factory with the method you will call:

```
var getData = function(){
    var canceller = $q.defer();

    var cancel = function(reason){
        canceller.resolve(reason);
    };

    var promise =
        $http.get(service.url + '/filters', { timeout: canceller.promise})
            .then(function(response){
               return response.data;
            });

    return {
        promise: promise,
        cancel: cancel
    };
};
```

Then you call it in this way:

```
var request = service.getData();
$scope.requests.push(request);
request.promise.then(function(movie){
    $scope.movies.push(movie);
    clearRequest(request);
}, function(reason){
    console.log(reason);
});
```

You then provide a method that will cancel the request:

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    var request = // retrieve the correct request from the requests array        
    request.cancel("User cancelled");
    // Remove the request from the array
};
```

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't seem to stop the promise from resolving anyway. I added a console.log statement to make sure that the request.cancel() is fired at the right time, and yet I still hit my breakpoint in the "then" afterwards. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know as I don't see your code, update your question with the code you are using

Comment: It's because in our system the requests to the server get queued (for various reasons). Apparently, cancelling a request that hasn't been sent to the server yet does absolute nothing as it will get sent afterwards.

Comment: if it's not  yet been sent, just remove it from the queue. Just for curiosity, why are you queueing requests? For performance reasons? How do you do that? Are you using some sort of angular bus?

Comment: We noticed a while back that our Entity Framework setup seemed to be struggling a lot with concurrent requests (either to the same tables, or to other tables, it didn't matter). Making sure the requests were queued sped up the application a lot. To queue it, we created an interceptor, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464945/add-queueing-to-angulars-http-service. 
Mind you, on other applications we don't notice this performance benefit, so we figure there's something wrong with our config (or database) for this project, but we couldn't figure out what it was.

Comment: @StevenLemmens I did not know about the interceptor, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So I have a few thoughts for your question.

**First** you could use ng-cloak which is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading.  I find this very helpful if I want the user to wait until all the data has returned to view the page. ex.

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

**Second** you could try a resolve. A resolve contains one or more promises that must resolve successfully before the route will change. This means you can wait for data to become available before actually changing routes.

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The directive needs to use the `$destroy` event to cancel operations in progress.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope, $http, $q) {
            var canceller = $q.defer();
            var cancel = function(reason){
                canceller.resolve(reason);
            };

            $http.get(url, { timeout: canceller.promise})
               .then(function(response){
                   $scope.data = response.data;
               });

           $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
               cancel("Scope destroyed");
           });
       }
    }
});
```

When the `ng-repeat` removes an item, it destroys the scope of the item. Use the `$destroy` event to cancel asynchronous operations in progress.

From the Docs:

> The `$destroy()` method is usually used by directives such as `ngRepeat` for managing the unrolling of the loop.
>
> Just before a scope is destroyed, a `$destroy` event is broadcasted on this scope. Application code can register a `$destroy` event handler that will give it a chance to perform any necessary cleanup.

--[AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy)